# Apache Camel timeout during finding data through a CustomProcessor

Tags: java, spring, jpa, apache-camel, dao

I seem to get timeout errors after 20 seconds. I have a custom processor the implements Processor. I inject a DAO and when finding the data within the custom processor it takes longer to find the data on the Apache Camel side and it timeouts. If I run the same code without Apache Camel it runs instantly. By doing a SELECT inside the CustomProcessor it takes longer to find the data.

The memory reference for the DAO are the same, so in the test the data is fetched immediately and the CustomProcessor hangs for 20 seconds before the data is receieved and it throws an Exception.

I am unable to figure out what is the cause of the problem.

I have located the code on Githib: https://github.com/rajivj2/example2

The problem is on line 27 of StatusHibernateDAO. I use a in memory database with only one table. There is only data populated.

When using the CustomProcessor without Apache Camel it works perfectly.

I hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Annotation Based configuration, the embedded Active MQ broker might be stopped unexpectedly, it’s good to use external broker (ex: tcp://host: 61616).

It seems QoS settings on the JMS endpoint is not working. You can the Header values from ProducerTemplate.

Since you are using producerTemplate.requestBody the activemq end point assumes that it is Request and Replay exchange(InOut) and since there is no response from route timeout occurring. If you want to implement  (InOut) follow the instructions at http://camel.apache.org/jms.html. Since your Routebuilder is InOnly, you need to send the disableReplyTo header from the ProducerTemplate.

Replace your test method testMessageSendToConsumerQueueRemoteId as

```
@Transactional
@Test
public void testMessageSendToConsumerQueueRemoteId() throws Exception {
    Status status = new Status();
    status.setUserId(10);
    statusDAO.save(status);

    Endpoint mockEndpoint = this.context.getEndpoint(properties.getProperty("activemq.destination"));       
    PollingConsumer consumer = mockEndpoint.createPollingConsumer();
    producerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader(source, "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?><example><remoteid>10</remoteid></example>","disableReplyTo","true");
    Status savedStatus = consumer.receive(100).getIn().getBody(Status.class);
    logger.info("savedStatus "+savedStatus.getID()+" "+savedStatus.getUserId());
    assertNotNull(savedStatus);
}
```

Replace your ContentEnricherProcessor’s process method as

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    Message message = exchange.getIn();
    Entity entity = (Entity) message.getBody();
    Status status = process(entity);
    message.setBody(status);
    exchange.getOut().setBody(status);
}
```

And your camel.property file should be

```
source=activemq:queue:deliverynotification
activemq.location=tcp://localhost:61616
activemq.destination=activemq:queue:responsenotification
```

If you want to receive back the generated response, you need to change your RouteBuilder.

```
from(properties.getProperty("source"))
.process(new ResponseProcessor())
.inOnly("direct:z")
.end();

from("direct:z")
.unmarshal()
.jaxb("com.example.entities.xml").convertBodyTo(Entity.class)
.multicast()
.to("direct:x")
.end();

from("direct:x").transacted()
.process((ContentEnricherProcessor) applicationContext.getBean("contentEnricherProcessor"))
.to(properties.getProperty("activemq.destination"));
```

Then change the producer patterns like

```
Status response = producerTemplate.requestBody(source, "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?><example><remoteid>11</remoteid></example>",Status.class);
```

Here is the ResponseProcessor process method

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    Message outMsg = exchange.getIn().copy();
    exchange.setOut(outMsg);
}
```

Camel ROCKS... you can implement almost any use case or pattern of Enterprise Integration :)

Comment: The problem is that I am unable to annotate the methods with Transactional on the DAO layer. These have to be at the Test level.

Comment: I have kind fixed it by adding ?disableReplyTo=false. For example, source=activemq:queue:deliverynotification?disableReplyTo=true. However by doing this causes another issue. When doing producerTemplate.requestBody it behaves like an InOnly message and returns the sent XML. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Your solution works, but I require the Transactional on the Test level rather than on the DAO layer. In case, the transaction fails everything will need to be rolled back. Can you please help?

Comment: Thank you. One solution was to disableReplyTo parameter. I would like to turn this of and use an alternative way. I require a InOut only without the use of the disableReplyTo. The only reason why I used a disableReplyTo is because the DAO code run faster. Can you please help?